# How do I use qmake to build multiple binaries in a single project?

Tags: qt, qmake

I'm writing a small qt app suite that consists of a set of small programs that work on the same set of files. They are organized like this:

> ```
> /
>   app1/
>     main.cpp
>   app2/
>     main.cpp
>   app3/
>     main.cpp
>   common/
>     project.h
>     project.cpp
>     somemore.h
>     somemore.cpp
>   appsuite.pro
> ```

When I do `qmake && make`, I want the following binaries to be built:

- app1/app1
- app2/app2
- app3/app3

How do I write `appsuite.pro` to work like this?
I have heard something about `.pri` files, but I could not figure out how to use them in my "situation".

Help appreciated,
jrh

Answer (score 37, accepted):

One way of doing it is to have a .pro file per subdirectory.

appsuite.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS = common app1 app2 app3
app1.depends = common
app2.depends = common
app3.depends = common
```

app1/app1.pro:

```
TARGET = app1
SOURCES = main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += ../common
LIBS += -L../common -lcommon
```

The common.pro file should build a static library you can then link into the binaries.

common/common.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG = staticlib
SOURCES = project.cpp more.cpp
HEADERS = project.h more.h
```

Comment: A .pri file merely contains other qmake commands.  Certainly they often list the files for inclusion in a project, but it isn't necessarily so.  For example, at work we have one that defines a target so that we can do a "make depends" and have the makefiles regenerated.

Comment: @cjhuitt .pri files weren't really relevant in this case so I've removed the reference.

Comment: After using this solution in my "Common" subdir project I get errors for missing Qt Libraries like:

`Common/localserver.h:4:19: fatal error: QThread: No such file or directory`

Comment: Additionally, you can use a `common.pri` that is included from the `app*.pro` files to centralize the `INCLUDEPATH` and `LIBS` directives.

Comment: Ok... For my case i think create subdirs for applications (e.g. ./app/* and ./app-cli/*) with *.pro separated files and create here symlinks like "./dependency-sources -> ../dependency-sources and build it as separated executables with using same source components. This is bad idea or not?

Comment: @PiedPiper i make it without symlinks (for compatible on platforms): 3 subdirs: cli, core, gui. core dir have core components, and cli, gui dirs have main-cli.cpp and main-gui.cpp (and other files for self), 3 *.pro files (cli, gui and linguist) in other subdir. It make 2 standalone apps (gui build first) and cli make using same core *.o files without recompile it. And after i run linguist for all sources. It works great.

Answer (score 11):

One way is to create your global project `appsuite.pro`, like this:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS = app1 app2 app3
```

The subprojects `app1.pro` and `app2.pro` should also be created for those applications alone, with a dependency regarding the common/ subdirectory

You can also specify other dependencies in appsuite.pro, for example if app1 depends on app2, as:

```
app1.depends = app2
```