# creating more than one dll in a qt project

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt4, qt-creator

I am working on a project in qt Creator and I would like to create a couple of dlls as well as an exe. Can I do this in one project or would I need to split my word into three separate projects?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use qmake to build multiple binaries in a single project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538398/how-do-i-use-qmake-to-build-multiple-binaries-in-a-single-project)

Comment: I'm not sure the question is the same although I agree that the accepted answer also applies to my quesiton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create three separate projects I am afraid. But you can have all three open at the one time in Qt Creator, which is always handy.