# Using QMake how can I build a project once for each main()

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, qmake

So, I am starting using unit test using catch with Qt (plain c++, but using qmake with .pro file).

Its a small project with the following files:

```
DatagramSocket.cpp/h
main.cpp                     - this contains a main() function
```

But also for the unit test it has the files:

```
catch.hpp
unittestdatagramsocket.cpp   - this contains a main() function
```

In my .pro file I can build the project normally like this:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt
# TARGET = unittest-UDPDatagram
TARGET = UDPDatagram

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    DatagramSocket.cpp \
    # unittestdatagramsocket.cpp


HEADERS += \
    DatagramSocket.h \
    catch.hpp

LIBS += \
    -lwsock32
    -lws2_32
```

And then I can run UDPDatagram.exe - it works.

Or I can build it for unit test like this:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt
TARGET = unittest-UDPDatagram
# TARGET = UDPDatagram

SOURCES += \
    # main.cpp \
    DatagramSocket.cpp \
    unittestdatagramsocket.cpp


HEADERS += \
    DatagramSocket.h \
    catch.hpp

LIBS += \
    -lwsock32
    -lws2_32
```

Then I can run unittest-UDPDatagram.exe - it works.

What I would like to do is for the build (whether debug or release) to build both every time. Is that possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use qmake to build multiple binaries in a single project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538398/how-do-i-use-qmake-to-build-multiple-binaries-in-a-single-project)

Comment: @Gluttton - it is kind of similar, thanks. I think I could use further ideas though and would like to keep it open a bit longer if possible to see if there are other options.

Comment: you can use `SUBDIRS` to make it. ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1538639/7943781

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, each .pro file is for just a single executable or library. But you can put the shared stuff in a separate .pro file and include it from the two .pro files, each one for a single program.

Comment: Thanks for that. But does this mean it has to be a separate project? or is there a way to link the two .pro files to build together (maybe like a sub-dirs project?) but still produce two executables? - or must I switch projects each time? Thanks!

Comment: Just create a simple batch file (createAll.bat) calling qmake for both .pro files and done :-)

Comment: awww.....I suppose so!, thanks :)    wanted to try to keep it build-able withing qtcreator, but its not priority.