# qmake: make both executable and static lib

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

Our project uses c++ and Qt and is build with qmake and .pro files.

We have a project structure as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538398/how-do-i-use-qmake-to-build-multiple-binaries-in-a-single-project). Which means a folder structure like this:

folder Myproject contains

- Myproject.pro
- Subdirectory App1
- Subdirectory App2
- Subdirectory Unittest
- Subdirectory Common

Each subdirectory has its own .pro file (app1.pro ; app2.pro ; unittest.pro ; common.pro) and a number of source code files.

common.pro has

```
TEMPLATE = lib
```

The others have

```
TEMPLATE = app
```

Which means that the staticlib generated from common can be included by the others.

There are now some classes in App1 which could easily be unittested, so we would like to be able to include them in Unittest as well. This means that App1 should be build both as an app and as a lib.

The current idea is to split the App1 folder into App1classes and App1main. App1classes would contain nearly everything and be build as a lib. App1main would contain only the main function. This means the lib from app1classes could be included by both app1main and unittest.

The question is whether there is a better way to do this, i.e. some way to adapt the app1.pro so it builds both an executable and a staticlib that can be included by others.

**edit**: I made two .pro's in the same folder, with a .pri for their common part, as suggested in the accepted answer. The reason I first thought this wouldn't work is because I thought you could only have one .pro file in each subdirectory, but you can have multiple if you write this in Myproject.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS = Common App1 App2 App1lib Unittest
App1lib.file = App1/App1lib.pro
```

If a .file is not determined for a subdir, it is assumed to be subdirname/subdirname.pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much easier to factor out `app1.pro` into `app1.pri` with `HEADERS`, `SOURCES`, `FORMS`, etc., and then include it from `app1lib.pro` and `app1app.pro`.